# Position: absolute causes page to zoom out

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

This might be a fairly obvious answer, but I don't see anything like this online.

Essentially, I have a responsive navbar that works fine on larger devices. The issue here is with mobile layouts. When I switch to mobile, the entire website is zoomed out like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVerf.png. Removing the line `right: -200px;` fixes this, but I need to move the content off the screen. Is this zoom behavior nextjs specific, and is there a fix? Thanks!

```css
.navigation-main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2% 6%;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.nav-links-main {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}

.nav-links-main a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-links-main ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-links-main ul li::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #f44336;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.nav-links-main ul li:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

.bars {
  width: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 822px) {
  /* make navbar responsive */

  .nav-links-main ul li {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
  }

  .nav-links-main {
    position: absolute;
    background: #f44336;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 200px;
    top: 0;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 1;
    right: -200px;
  }

  .bars {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
    <div className="nav-links-main" id="navLinks">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link href="/">
              <a>HOME</a>
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link href="about">
              <a>ABOUT</a>
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link href="blog">
              <a>BLOG</a>
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link href="contact">
              <a>CONTACT</a>
            </Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <a onClick={openMenu}>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars} className="bars" />
      </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` included in your page's `<head>`?

Comment: I did not, that seems like such an obvious thing to check. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your _app.js add this code in the head tag and if any meta tag with name viewport is exist then replace it with this -

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```